# Showing that two wavefunctions are orthogonal

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I have two function:

- $\Psi_A(x,0)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{6}}\phi_0(x)+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\phi_1(x)+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\phi_2(x)$
- $\Psi_C(x,0)=\sqrt{\frac{3}{8}}\phi_0(x)+\sqrt{\frac{5}{8}}\phi_2(x)$

I have to show they are linear independent:

> [image: Blockquote]

The solutions is shown below and doesn't much my answer as it says $\Psi_A$ and $\Psi_C$ are linear independent  i was wondering where i went wrong:

> [image: Blockquote]

In the context of this answer there is another function  $\Psi_A(x,0)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{6}}\phi_0(x)+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\phi_1(x)-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\phi_2(x)$ which in eariler part we have shown that $\Psi_A$ and $\Psi_B$ are linearly independent.

Comment: not sure where those screenshots are from but I would find a better source. Their claim "not zero therefore not linearly independent" is just wrong. Two vectors can be linearly independent and still have a non-trivial overlap (consider $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$ on the plane).

Comment: Problem sheet: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2013/assignments/MIT8_04S13_ps4.pdf Answer sheet: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2013/assignments/MIT8_04S13_ps4_sol.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different concepts in here that I think you are mixing up. One is orthogonality, the other is linear independence. States that are orthogonal are necessarily linearly independent, but not all linearly independent states have zero overlap (i.e. are orthogonal).

The solution you posted does not say that $\psi_\text{A}$ and $\psi_\text{B}$ are orthogonal, but rather that $\phi_n$ are orthogonal. Since $\psi_\text{A}$ contains $\phi_2$, but $\psi_\text{B}$ does not, they cannot be linearly dependent. But that does not mean the states themselves are orthogonal (they are not).

Comment: "Since $\psi_\text{A}$ contains $\phi_2$, but $\psi_\text{B}$ does not" - you presumably mean $\phi_1$.

Comment: I was refering to the $\psi_\text{B}$ from the original problem, because that's what the solution mentions. If it was  $\psi_\text{C}$ as the OP mentions in his first set of equations, you'd be right.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I'll leave my comment, as my mistake might well be repeated by others :-).